# Is vertx Context newly created on handler execution or shared handler in all executions?

Tags: vert.x

I'm creating a microservice with vertx, vertx-grpc. I want to provide a MDC for logging.

I want to do it in a similar way to:
https://github.com/tsegismont/vertx-context-logging-experiments

I'm not sure if using this approach is correct or not:

```java
 ContextInternal context = (ContextInternal) Vertx.currentContext();
 context.localContextData().getOrDefault("userId", "defValue");
```

Vertx documentation does not make it clear to me whether the context is created for each **handler execution** or the **context is unique and shared between all handler executions** (invalidating this kind of approach).

Answer (score 1):

> Using a context is usually transparent, Vert.x will manage contexts implicitly when deploying a Verticle, registering an Event Bus handler, etc…​ However the Vert.x API provides several ways to interact with a Context allowing for manual context switching.

When not manually playing/handling contexts you handlers will be executed on the same context. 
For more info you can check this documentation to get detailed information anot context API and handling.

[Dealing with contexts](https://www.julienviet.com/advanced-vertx-guide/#_dealing-with-contexts)

Comment: Many thanks. Impossible to implement MDC. I've checked vertx 4.0.0-milestone1, ContextImpl has a localDataMap that looks great and provides this functionality.